# Existence of solutions to a nonlinear algebraic equation

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

How can we prove that equation (1)  has solutions for every $p$.  I mean, is there an analytic method that can be used  to show  that there exist solutions for every $p$ for this  nonlinear equation:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1^2 x_2  \cdots x_{p-1} x_p+x_1 &=& 1 \, ,\\
&&\\
 x_1 x_2^2 x_3 \cdots x_{p-1} x_p+x_1 x_2 &=& 1 \, ,\\
&&\\
x_1 x_2 x_3^2 x_4 \cdots x_{p-1} x_p+x_1 x_2 x_3&=& 1\, , \\
&&\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
&&\\
x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 \cdots x_{p-1} x_p^2+x_1 x_2 \cdots  x_p&=& 1\, .
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

For example,  let ($p=3$). Then we have:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1^2 x_2  x_3+x_1 &=& 1 \, ,\\
&&\\
 x_1 x_2^2 x_3 +x_1 x_2 &=& 1 \, ,\\
&&\\
x_1 x_2 x_3^2 +x_1 x_2 x_3&=& 1\, .
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

So is there an analytic method for existence of solution for equation (2). For this example I used MAPLE software and got these solutions:

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
a &=&  0.658418845314095780 \, ,\\
&&\\
b &=& 0.849466898144101812 \, ,\\
&&\\
c&=& 0.927561975482924960  \, .
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Existence of solutions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that no $x_k$ can vanish. If you put $ u :=x_1x_2\dots x_p  $  the system gives inductively, for $k=1,\dots,p$:

$$\frac{1}{x_1 x_2\dots x_k}=1+u+\dots+u^k . $$

In particular $u$ solves
$$\frac{1}{u}=1+u+\dots+u^p . $$
Incidentally, $u\neq 1$, so we can express the solutions to the systems simply as
$$x_k=\frac{u^{k}-1}{u^{k+1}-1},$$
in terms of the solutions $u\neq 1$ to the equation

$$u^{p+2}-2u+1=0. $$

Also note that, by elementary arguments, if $p$ is even the latter equation has a unique real solution (besides $u=1$), which is positive, while if $p$ is odd it has a positive and a negative solution (besides $u=1$). So the system has one or two real solutions according whether $p$ is even or odd, and in any case a unique solution 
if $x_k$ are assumed to be real and positive.

To complete the analytic solution, we may solve $u^{p+2}-2u+1=0$ by
series using the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_Lagrange_inversion_formula) to invert $u-u^{p+2}/2$ at $1/2$: for the solution $0<u_p<1$ one gets

$$u_p=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {pk+2k\choose k}  \frac{2^{-pk-2k}}{pk + k+1}.$$

For instance, 
$$u_3=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {5k\choose k}  \frac{32^{-k}}{4k+1}=0.5187900635...$$
that corresponds to the solutions $x_1=a, x_2=b, x_3=c$ you got by MAPLE.

Comment: Dear Professor P.Majer

Thank you very much for your creative and complete answer . It was amazing for me your attitude to this nonlinear equation.
 I have two questions , First It is possible to explain how do you get this formula for $u_p$ from  Lagrange inversion formula 
 and second  would you tell me why $0< u_p<1 $?
I mean is there an elementary way to show that for every $p$,  The equation 
$u^{p+2}-2u+1=0$, 
 has a positive real solution between zero and one.
 
Thank you again for your favor to answer to my question.

Comment: You're welcome! 1) The series for the solution is a very standard application of the Lagrange inversion formula  to $f(u):=u(1- u^{p+1} /2 )$. Use the binomial series to expand $f^{-m}=u^{-m}(1- u^{p+1} /2 )^{-m}$, then find the residue at $0$ extracting the coefficient of $u^{-1}$. 2) Yes, write the equation as $u^p=2u-1$ and compare the values of both LHS and RHS  at $0$, and their derivatives at $u=1$. Also, by convexity of $u^p$ there are at most $2$ positive solutions.

Comment: That $u_p$ can't be larger than $1$ also follows immediately from the first equation for it, $1/u=1+u+\dots+u^p$.

Comment: I would appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: The latter equation for $u$ also comes from a generalization of the Golden Ratio ($p=1$): dividing a  segment into  $p+1$ sub-intervals that are in a geometric progression of $p+1$ terms, whose next term is the segment itself.
Also, $u_p$ is the limit of the ratio of two consecutive terms $F_m/F_{m+1}$ of a linear recursive sequence $F_m$  where each term is the sum of the preceding $p+1$ terms e.g. starting with $1,1,\dots,1.$
http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL18/Szczyrba/sz3.pdf

For instance, 0.5187900635… is the reciprocal of the "Tetranacci constant" http://oeis.org/A000288

Comment: I know what you mean professor P.Majer because I have been working on Fibonacci sequences for two years, thank you so much for you information.